# How to display images from Picture Directory ?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

I want to display pictures in the Pictures library. I get pictures and bind data.

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> myPictures = await picturesFolder.GetFilesAsync();
var mydata = from file in myPictures select new { Subtitle = "subtitle", Title = "title", Image = this.getImage(file.Path) };

this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = mydata;
```

This is getImage() for set BitmapImage.

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> getImage(string finename)
{
    StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
    StorageFile file = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(stream);

    return bitmap;
 }
```

But pictures are not displayed.I think this is because of async function, but I don't know the solution. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how do you use the data that set to `DefaultViewModel`, but yeah, it looks like the `async` method is your problem.

What you need to do is to somehow `await` each call to `getImage()`. One way to do this is to use `async` lambda in your `select`. But to do that, you need to use the method syntax.

When you do that, you will have `IEnumerable<Task<a>>` (where `a` is your anonymous type), but you need just `IEnumerable<a>`. To get that, use [`Task.WhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766.aspx) (which will return `Task<a[]>`) and then `await` its result:

```
var tasks = myPictures.Select(
    async file => new { Subtitle = "subtitle", Title = "title", Image = await getImage(file.Path) });
var data = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This will execute all `getImage()`s at once, which may not be the most efficient solution. If you don't want that, you would need different solution.

Answer (score 1):

svick's solution seems like should work, but as he/she said - it might not be the most efficient solution. A better solution for a folder with unknown number of files is to use data virtualization with `FileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector()`. That works best with a converter.

Something I have used:

**Getting a virtualized file list and binding to a ListView**

```
private async void GetPicturesFromGalleryFolder()
{
    var queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Shallow;
    queryOptions.IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable;
    queryOptions.SortOrder.Clear();

    var sortEntry = new SortEntry {PropertyName = "System.DateModified", AscendingOrder = false};
    queryOptions.SortOrder.Add(sortEntry);
    queryOptions.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    var fileQuery = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    var fileInformationFactory =
        new FileInformationFactory(
            fileQuery,
            ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,
            0,
            ThumbnailOptions.None,
            true);

    MyListView.ItemsSource = fileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector();
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image
            Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converters:IStorageItemInformationToBitmapImageConverter}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**IStorageItemInformationToBitmapImageConverter**

```
public class IStorageItemInformationToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var fileInfo = value as FileInformation;

        if (fileInfo != null)
        {
            var bi = new BitmapImage();

            // The file is being opened asynchronously but we return the BitmapImage immediately.
            SetSourceAsync(bi, fileInfo);
            return bi;

        }

        return null;
    }

    private async void SetSourceAsync(BitmapImage bi, FileInformation fi)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = await fi.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                await bi.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore failure
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this!  `FileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector() `