# How to implement a lazy load GridView on WinRT?

Tags: gridview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, lazy-loading, scrollviewer

I need to implement a gridview of thumbs. But when my app hit 200 thumbs, it starts to get memory problems(of course). I need to implement a lazy load but I don't know how to detect where the scrollviewer are on the gridview so I could try to load more images once it reaches the end.

Here's my gridview layout:
[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`ISupportIncrementalLoading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx) in your source collection to support data virtualization and the `GridView` will handle requesting more items itself. Also make sure you haven't changed the `ItemsPanel` of your `GridView` to one that doesn't support UI virtualization - e.g. `VariableSizedWrapGrid`.

Also make sure you don't simply have a memory leak for any other reason. Typically a 200 items grid that is UI-virtualized (the default) should not use that much memory unless your thumbs are actually much bigger resolution than what you need to display them. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730496/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-in-windows-store-apps) for ways to debug leaks.

Comment: thanks, man.
do you know where I could find information on how to load the image in a smaller size?

Comment: Any workaround to use `ISupportIncrementalLoading` in `VariableSizedWrapGrid` ?

Comment: @adheus Check the [Tim Heuer method](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapLoadExtensions.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit to get inspired on how to load an image at a specific resolution, though if you can control the source of your images - it is better to simply create/request the images at a specific resolution.

Comment: @Xyroid I haven't actually ever used `ISupportIncrementalLoading` before, though I have used [`FileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.bulkaccess.fileinformationfactory.getvirtualizedfilesvector.aspx) as in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420275/how-to-display-images-from-picture-directory). What is the specific thing you would need in your workaround? `VariableSizedWrapGrid` isn't virtualized, so even if it does works with data virtualization it would leak the data.

Comment: @Xyroid I would suggest not using `VariableSizedWrapGrid` with more than a few to few dozen items. If you really need want to though - you should probably look into lazy loading the data (e.g. images) when the items are scrolled into view and some sort of a circular buffer to unload the data that wasn't recently requested or went out of view. Then also use attached properties to bind `GridViewItem`'s `VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan/ColumnSpan` properties to the data items or try walking the visual tree from `ItemTemplate` to set the span of the parent GridViewItem. All hacky stuff.

Comment: Thanks Filip, I would post the question, if I will face.

Comment: A good way to get images at specified size is to use the Windows-managed thumbnails cache, so that the thumbnails get scaled and managed by the OS. You can do that with the `FileInformationFactory` constructor, or by calling `StorageFile/FileInformation.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 256, ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail)` - where 256 is the larger dimension of the image. If you do that - the image won't need to be scaled every time you open it and will instead be loaded from the thumbnails cache database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create thumbs by yourself: Only create smaller images - and that's all.

```
   new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path)) {DecodePixelWidth = 200}
```